# Stale environment variables in Jupyter Notebooks running in vscode using a conda environment kernel

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, conda, vscode-extensions

I'm using jupyter inside a conda environment in vscode on Ubuntu and all works great. However, recently I've experienced issues with AWS access tokens expiring inside my jupyter notebook.

It seems that these access tokens get cached at some level, either in the code environment or somewhere in the jupyter layer, but I couldn't figure out where and how to clean it up.

Example:

I'm using `aws-vault` to generate SSO credentails, that can be accessed in the environment.

After starting a session, I can access the `AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION` from my terminal:

```sh
echo $AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION
```

> 2022-04-20T17:40:36Z

when I start vscode, open a terminal, I get the same.

When I activate my environment, and run

```sh
python -c "import os;print(os.environ['AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION'])"
```

I get the same.

However, when I open a new jupyter notebook and select the same environment, and run

```py
import os
print(os.environ['AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION'])
```

I get

> 2022-04-06T11:09:03Z

I've tried locating any files that could cache the env variables either in the conda env or jupyter extension. I've also tried restarting vscode and the machine itself - all without success.

Can anyone help me clean this up?

Thanks!!

**Edit:**

Another example:

If I set in my terminal

```sh
export FOO=BAR
```

then I can access `$FOO` as expected through the terminal and jupy notebook within vscode.

Then I close vscode, run

`unset FOO`

reboot the machine, start vscode new and open a new notebook with the same conda environment.

Within, running

```py
import os
print(os.environ['FOO'])
```

**STILL** returns `BAR`

Comment: I think jupyter notebook uses a separate session than the integrated terminal. Are you defining `AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION` environment variable anywhere in jupyter notebook?

Comment: @monte no, if I start a fresh notebook, `AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION` is already defined in the environment - even after restart and deleting + re-installing the conda env

Comment: how are you defining those env variables? because I have run into similar issues, and what I understood, was if I define environment variables in `.vscode/settings.json`, the integrated terminal has access to those env variables but not teh jupyter notebook, the workaround I used was to define environment variables for jupyter notebook in a top code cell like `import os; os.environ["MY_ENV"] = "test"`

Comment: is `aws-vault` setting `AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION` variable? what I am trying to say is it will be worth to look into how (or who) `AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION` is getting defined

Comment: @monte yes, this is what I'm trying to understand. `aws-vault` does set these env variables. If I start vscode with them defined (after running aws-vault), they appear in the integrated terminal as well. If I run code before, they arfe not there as expected. But for the jupyter notebook, they are there either way - and they have the same cached value

Comment: So I don't get where the jupyter kernel gets the environment from, because it's definitely not from the process that starts vscode

Comment: In my case, closing and opening VSCode solved this issue (not a proper solution, tough). It seems it haven't worked in your case (maybe something changed in VSCode or the Jupyter extension regarding that since when you posted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be [an issue in the vscode-jupyter](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9774) extension, that somehow stores the environment variables in the `kernel.json` file.

At the moment of writing this, the issue is still open. Working in ubuntu, [this workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9774#issuecomment-1110328329) from the issue's thread works for me:

> 1. Close code completely
> 2. `find ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter*`
> 3. `code .`
> 4. Run a notebook and it will pick up the changes.

Answer (score 1):

With closed vscode, issue the following command to delete cache:

```
find ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter* -name kernel.json -delete
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9774#issuecomment-1110328329